# Modify and delete document in Cloudant IBM Database

Tags: database, cloudant

Is it possible to modify document or delete in Cloudant Database by query?

Comment: Updating and deleting documents seems fairly fundamental to a database, no? What did you find in the documentation? FYI there are plenty of results when searching the web for ways to update and delete documents. As written, this question is off-topic, as there is no programming question, just a request for documentation). If you are running into a specific issue when trying to update or delete a document, *great* - post *that* as a question, along with your code and where you're stuck. As of now, we don't even know what language you're using. So this is rather unclear as well as broad.

Comment: @DavidMakogon if you don't know Cloudant database just sit quiet. It is something different than ordinary sql. You just show your lack of knowledge giving me -1 for this question.

Comment: I know about Cloudant. The issue is with your question, a yes/no question. And again, something discoverable with minimal effort. This question, though, does not show any minimal effort, hence the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the questioner is looking for equivalent functionality to SQL's:

```
UPDATE db SET x = 10 WHERE y > 100;
```

If that is the question then the answer is that Cloudant does not have such functionality, only an atomic [update](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#update) operation.

The equivalent of the `UPDATE` statement could be achieved by combining a call to the [Cloudant Query API](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#query) and making updates using the [bulk API](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#bulk-operations).

Another option is to use the [couchtato](https://github.com/cliffano/couchtato) iterator tool which allows bulk changes to be made to Cloudant databases.

Comment: Thank you! But it's not it. In Cloudant database you write query in json. I can't find syntax in json to modify or delete document. Cloudant is nosql database document

Comment: This command PUT /$DATABASE/$DOCUMENT_ID HTTP/1.1 I have to write in query?

Answer (score 0):

To delete a document you have to know the document _id, if you do not know the _id then you have to look for the document in your db, retrieve it and then get the _id.
To retrieve a document you can use a selector. For example, let's say that you have a document that contains a "name" field, your selector would be something like
selector = {"name": {"$eq": "name that you want"}}
So for python code you would have something like

```
def retrieve_db_data(db_name, selector):
    client = connect_to_db()
    db = client[db_name]

    results = db.get_query_result(selector)
    data = results.all()
    return data
```

In "data" you will have the _id
then you can use something like this to delete the data

```
def delete_document(db_name, doc_id):
    client = connect_to_db()
    client.connect()
    db = client[db_name]
    document = db[doc_id]
    document.delete()
```